# excel vba - search for a value in an array

Tags: excel, vba

How do I select a value from an array, and write it on a cell, based on a condition?

I have this:

```
Dim Material As Variant

Dim Material1 As Variant
Material1 = Array("16", "20", "26", "32", "40", "50", "63", "70")

Dim Material2 As Variant
Material2 = Array("12", "16", "22", "28", "34", "42", "58", "65")

Dim Rows as Long
For Rows = 9 to lastrow

If Range("P"&Rows).Value <> 0 then

If Range("W"&Rows).value = Material1 then
Material = Material1
'material can be Material2 also, but I would do the same IF


If Range("Z"&Rows).Value > 2 then
Range ("X"&Rows).value = ' this is where I fail, I want to write here a value from Material1 (looping through position 1, 2, etc...)that does the opposite to my condition, i.e. <2 (this is related with formulas in the sheet)
```

I didn't forget to "end" the IFs and to move to "Next Rows"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a cell's value with the entire `Material1` array here:

```
If Range("W"&Rows).value = Material1 then
```

If you want to check if the value in Column "W" equals to one of the elements in `Material1`, you can use the `Match` function:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("W" & Rows).Value, Material1, 0)) Then
```

Comment: I understand. But yes, I am trying to compare the content of a cell with the entire array. If the cell content is "Material1" (text), I want it to search for a value inside an array called "Material1".

Comment: @ZedA. not sure I understand, you want to see if text in column "W" is "Material1", then do what ? what value to find in `Material1` array ?

Comment: yes, if the text in column "W" is "Material1" I want it to search for a value in an array with the same name. The value must satisfy my condition, which is related with column Z. If column Z is <2, i want it to search for a value in that array that, when it's written in column X, changes my column Z to < 2. Not sure if im clear!

Comment: "while" the value in column X is >2, I want it to test different values from the selected array.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your arrays:

```
For i = LBound(Materials1) To UBound(Materials1)
    'check for value using Materials(i)
Next i
```

Comment: And how do I select the value that satisfies my condition, and write it let's say on Range("x"&rows)  ?

Comment: Write code to test your condition againt elements of array, then write it `Range("x"&rows) = Materials(i)`.